# Joomla 3.4 cannot upload image after changing live_site configuration

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm using Joomla 3.4, `live_site` attribute in `configuration.php` file was set empty before.
I change the site URL from `http://example.com` into `http://example.com/subdirectory`, when I insert uploaded images, in the user site, images were loaded from `http://example.com/images` instead of `http://example.com/subdirectory/images`, that's why they are not display.
I follow some instructions in the Internet and found that the issue can be solved if I set `$live_site = "http://example.com/subdirectory"`.
But, after setting `$live_site`, when I upload images the page (media manager in administrator) is unstopped loading and in the status bar of browser I see that there is `Uploading (20%)` or `Uploading (8%)` message.
I didn't change in directory permission and for `images`, `tmp` directory, they are still 777.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting `live_site` in `configuration.php` you may be able to solve the issue by setting `Rewritebase /subdirectory` in the `.htaccess` file.

Setting permissions to 777 should not be necessary and this is not recommended from a security point of view.

Comment: Hi, @Robertson, I had added this line in `.htaccess` file before asking question. It doesn't solve my problem. Thanks for you answer.